# The integral of sin function and it's relation with double factorial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I was trying to prove:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^{n}{x}\,dx}}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^{n+1}{x}\,dx}}\to 1$$ when $n \to\infty$

If this is true, then we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2n!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2\frac{1}{2n+1}\to\pi/2$$

am I on the right way? or there is some other way to prove the second fomula?

Answer (score 1):

Using [these formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial) we get

$$\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n - 1)!!(2n + 1)} = \frac{2^n n!}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!} (2n + 1)} = \frac{1}{4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n} (2n + 1)}$$

Now $C_n = \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{n + 1}$ are called [Catalan-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and from Stirling's approximation we know $C_n \sim \frac{4^n}{n^{3/2} \sqrt{\pi}}$, which yields
$$\frac{1}{4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n} (2n + 1)} \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n^{-3/2}(n + 1)(2n + 1)} \sim  \frac{\sqrt{n\pi}}{2}$$

I guess that you have forgotten a square, since 
$$\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n - 1)!!}\right)^2 \frac{1}{2n + 1} \to \frac{\pi}{2}$$
holds by the above calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Recalling the definition of the Beta function in the form $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{m}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{2}
 $$ we have $$\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+1}\left(x\right)dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)dx}=\frac{B\left(\frac{n+2}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\rightarrow1
 $$ where the last limit can be calculated with the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function). For the second limit you have only to consider the relations $$\left(2n-1\right)!!=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{2^{n}n!}
 $$ $$\left(2n\right)!!=2^{n}n!$$ and the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 0):

You are right: if 
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n+1}(x)\,dx}=1 \tag{1}$$
then:
$$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.\tag{2} $$
For instance, Buttazzo exploits this argument for finding the value of [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product). On the other hand, $(1)$ follows from the log-convexity of moments. If we set $I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx$, we clearly have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}I_n = 0$, and:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1} x^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \tag{3}$$
($I_n$ is a moment) so by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $I_n\cdot I_m \leq I_{\frac{m+n}{2}}^2$, i.e. $n\to\log I_n$ is midpoint-convex. Since $n\to \log I_n$ is also a continuous map (for $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$), it follows that $I_n$ is log-convex and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{I_n}{I_{n+1}}$ exists. Due to the [Stoltz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) and integration by parts, such limit has to be $\color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle the quotient of integrals: Let $x = \arcsin y.$ We get

$$\tag 1 \frac{\int_0^1y^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}{\int_0^1y^{n+1}(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}.$$

Note the denominator is smaller than the numerator, so this quotient is always $>1.$ To work on an upper bound, let $a\in (0,1).$ Claim:

$$\frac{\int_0^ay^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}{\int_a^1y^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}\to 0.$$

Why? The integral upstairs $\to 0$ geometrically, while the denominator is greater than $\int_a^1y^n\,dy \sim 1/(n+1).$

Now write $(1)$ as

$$\frac{\int_0^ay^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy + \int_a^1y^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}{\int_0^ay^{n+1}(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy + \int_a^1 y^{n+1}(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}$$ $$\tag 2 \le \frac{\int_0^ay^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy + \int_a^1y^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}{ a\int_a^1 y^{n}(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy}.$$

Divide the top and bottom of $(2)$ by $\int_a^1y^n(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\, dy.$ Then use the claim to see $(2)$ is

$$\frac{o(1) + 1}{a}.$$

It follows that the $\limsup$ of $(2)$ is $\le 1/a.$ Since $a$ was anything in $(0,1),$ we have the $\limsup$ of $(2)$ is $\le 1.$ Recalling $1$ was always a lower bound, we have shown the desired limit is $1.$